# I'm wondering if it's possible to check if it finds an id in the table resuser, can I exclude the corresponding resid from getting selected?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT *
FROM rescar
WHERE 
rescar.maxseats > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resuser WHERE rescar.resid = 
resuser.resid) 
AND (tidspunkt > cast(extract(epoch from current_timestamp) as integer)) 
AND rescar.id != 32
ORDER BY tidspunkt ASC;
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to check if it finds an id in the table resuser, can I exclude the corresponding resid from getting selected?

The rescar table is info on a car and how many seats it has available etc.
The resuser table is just a table with resid and id where resid is the car, and id is the id of the user that wants to ride with that car. This also selects multiple fields with the same resid as they have multiple persons that wants to ride with that car.

Comment: You have a column of type integer with the name `timestamp` ? Please don't do that: timestamp is a (non-reserved) keyword for a ... datatype *timestamp*

Comment: No, I just translated from Norwegian, it's not called timestamp

Comment: `if it finds an id in the table resuser, can I exclude the corresponding resid from getting selected?` Excluded from *what* ? From contributing to the aggregate, or should the whole aggregate disappear ?

Comment: Like if it finds id 32 on resid 30 in resuser, then it wont return the reservation with resid 30